Grainy texture overlay (not a physical screen protector) on the monitor screen
I have a Xiaomi Android device and there I have a setting to add a grainy screen texture and control the intensity of it. I like this feature as it gives a paperlike experience and is eye-comforting. So I wonder if there is any way to achieve the same effect on my desktop screen.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
